# MYSQL: Tricky Query - need to build intermedia Variable?

Tags: mysql

let´s assume we have the following table

```
_________________________________________________________________________
|FlightNo | DepartureDate       | Origin  | Destination | Flightduration |
_________________________________________________________________________
| IB233   | 2018-12-31 09:30:45 | Berlin   | Barcelona  | 200            |
| IB222   | 2019-01-01 12:20:34 | Barcelona| Rome       | 100            |
| LE111   | 2019-01-01 11:11:11 | Rome     | NY         | 400            |
__________________________________________________________________________
```

Now I want to calculate the timedifference between the Destination of NY and start in Berlin. **I want to check whether the whole flightduration is < 660 min**.

I worked out this, but it doesn´t work ..

```
SELECT 
  TIMEDIFF(
    (SELECT adddate(DepartureDate, INTERVAL FlightDuration  
MINUTE) 
     FROM flightexecution 
     where ICAO_Code_Origin = 'Berlin'), 
    (SELECT DepartureDate 
     FROM flightexecution 
     where ICAO_Code_Destination = 'NY' AND ICAO_Origin NOT LIKE 'Berlin' AND)
) from flightexecution ;
```

MySQL is giving me just an 'OK' as an result, which means that somehting is wrong...

Could you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a self join query like this

```
SELECT
    A.Origin,
    (TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_DIFF(A.DepartureDate, C.DepartureDate))/60 - A.FlightDuration - B.FlightDuration) AS `Transfer time (minutes)`,
    A.DepartureDate,
    (TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_DIFF(A.DepartureDate, C.DepartureDate))/60 + C.FlightDuration) AS `Overall Duration (minutes)`
FROM
    flightexecution A INNER JOIN
    flightexecution B 
        ON A.Destination = B.Origin INNER JOIN
    flightexecution C 
        ON B.Destination = C.Origin 
WHERE
    A.Origin = 'Berlin'
    AND C.Destination = 'NY'
```

Comment: Edited the query to get total duration between DepartureDate and arrivalDate.  See if this helps

Comment: Origin | Transfer Time | DepartureDate | Overall Duration

Comment: Where Transfer Time is for example when i start in Berlin i fly first to Barcelona, then from Barcelona to Rome and in the end from Rome to NY. So how much time am i waiting at the airport wihtout flying?

Comment: Updated query to calculate "Transfer time" as well.  Hope this solves your question.